# Searching an array of associate arrays for two matching parameters

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I have a loop that builds an array of associative arrays that looks like this:

```
array(
    'foo' => '',
    'bar' => '',
    'thingys' => array()
)
```

on each iteration of the loop, I want to search through the array for an associate array that's '`foo`' and '`bar`' properties match those of the current associate array. If it exists I want to append the thingys property of the current associative array to the match. Otherwise append the entire thing.
I know how to do this with for loops, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do this with an array function. I'm on php 5.3.

Example

```
<?php 
$arr = array(
    array(
        'foo' => 1,
        'bar' => 2,
        'thing' => 'apple'
    ),
    array(
        'foo' => 1,
        'bar' => 2,
        'thing' => 'orange'
    ),
    array(
        'foo' => 2,
        'bar' => 2,
        'thing' => 'apple'
    ),
);

$newArr = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $matchFound = false;
    for ($j=0; $j < count($newArr); $j++) { 
        if ($arr[$i]['foo'] === $newArr[$j]['foo'] && $arr[$i]['bar'] === $newArr[$j]['bar']) {
            array_push($newArr[$j]['thing'], $arr[$i]['things']);
            $matchFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$matchFound) {

        array_push($newArr,
            array(
                'foo' => $arr[$i]['foo'],
                'bar' => $arr[$i]['bar'],
                'things' => array($arr[$i]['thing'])
            )
        );
    }
}

/*Output
$newArr = array(
    array(
        'foo' => 1,
        'bar' => 2,
        'things' => array('orange', 'apple')
    ),
    array(
        'foo' => 2,
        'bar' => 2,
        'things' => array('apple')
    ),
)
*/
 ?>
```

Comment: sounds confusing. Can you add a sample of how your end result should look like?

Comment: And your current loop, etc.

Comment: I added a loop to the example along with expected output.

Comment: I think that `foo` and `bar` **keys** are fixed, known values, right? of what kind? is only alphabetic, alphanumeric, etc...

Comment: On second iteration, should `apple` get replaced by `orange`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible through a built-in function, but I think no. Something can be implemented through `array_map`, but anyway you have to perform a double loop.

I propose you a one-loop solution using a temporary array (`$keys`) as index of already created `$newArr` items, based on `foo` and `bar`; elements of original array are processed through a `foreach` loop, and if a `$keys` element with first key as `foo` value and second key as `bar` value exists, then the current `thing` value is added to the returned key index of `$newArr`, otherwise a new `$newArray` element is created.

```
$newArr = $keys = array();
foreach( $arr as $row )
{
    if( isset( $keys[$row['foo']][$row['bar']] ) )
    { $newArr[$keys[$row['foo']][$row['bar']]]['thing'][] = $row['thing']; }
    else
    {
        $keys[$row['foo']][$row['bar']] = array_push( $newArr, $row )-1;
        $newArr[$keys[$row['foo']][$row['bar']]]['thing'] = array( $row['thing'] );
    }
}
unset( $keys );
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/4IZXU)**</kbd>

#### Edit: array_map variant

This is the same solution above, using `array_map` instead of `foreach` loop. Note that also your original code can be converted in this way.

```
$newArr = $keys = array();
function filterArr( $row )
{
    global $newArr, $keys;
    if( isset( $keys[$row['foo']][$row['bar']] ) )
    { $newArr[$keys[$row['foo']][$row['bar']]]['thing'][] = $row['thing']; }
    else
    {
        $keys[$row['foo']][$row['bar']] = array_push( $newArr, $row )-1;
        $newArr[$keys[$row['foo']][$row['bar']]]['thing'] = array( $row['thing'] );
    }
}

array_map( 'filterArr', $arr );
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/Vm7AD)**</kbd>

Comment: OP's quote: `I know how to do this with for loops, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do this with an array function`

Comment: @Trix Yes, I well know, as you can see at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: You would better not try to reconfigure the questions, I think. the OP, has clearly stated that she/he is not after such a solution

Comment: You may edit the whole answer body, now that you found a so called, `Edit: array_map variant`

Comment: @Trix added `array_map` variant. Please note than I don't “try to reconfigure the questions” **in no way**. I answer to the question, then I suggest a variant to original code.

Comment: @Trix (previous comment written before yor last comment): I prefer no-destructive editing.